# Express JS fetch proper JSON with Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am working on WebAPI on ExpressJS. I am fetching data from MySQL database by using node module mysql. I have a mater and a detail table let say

Countries(ID, Name, Code)

States (ID, Name, CountryId)

Now I want to query the data in JSON as following:

```
{
  "country":{
              "ID" : 1,
              "Name" : "United States of America"
              "Code" : "USA"
              "Cities" : 
              [
               {
                "1",
                "Alabama",
                "AL"
               },
               {
                "2",
                "Alaska",
                "AK"
               },
               {
                "3",
                "California",
                "CA"
               }
              ]
            }
}
```

How can I query data in the above format?
Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I query data in the above format?

You can't because this is not a valid JSON. No matter what you do, you will never be able to represent your data in that format.

To represent data coming from a relational database as a JavaScript nested objects and arrays, it will be easiest to use an ORM like Sequelize, Bookshelf, ORM2 or Waterline. See:

- http://docs.sequelizejs.com/
- http://bookshelfjs.org/
- https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2
- http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm

ORM is an Object-Relational Mapper and lets you map the relational model to objects, which is exactly what you're trying to do here.

Comment: So what would you suggest? Because when I query the data, it repeats the master data for each of the detail record.